# Backup devices with script

Tags: bash, backup, expect

I have this script:

```
[root@vmlnx01 ~]# cat /bin/Scripts/SMB.sh
#!/bin/bash
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
/usr/bin/expect /bin/Scripts/bk-SMB.sh  $line
done < /home/backup/bk-SMB.txt
```

This script reads bk-SMB.txt file and pass on content like variable (line by line) to bk-SMB.sh, it works but takes a lot of time because I have 135 devices (and increasing). How can i improve the script to reduce the time? For example: pass variable by batches. Thanks for your ideas and help.

Comment: What happens if you just put the expect script in the background? Can you have 135 backups running simultaneously? Otherwise, you might want to investigate [tag:gnu-parallel]. BTW, quote the `$line` argument to expect; and `.sh` is an odd extension for an expect script (`.exp` would be typical)

Comment: Still using gnu-parallel script run line by line (not int parallel): `[root@vmlnx01 Scripts]# parallel "/usr/bin/expect /bin/Scripts/bk-SMB.sh {}" < /home/backup/bk-SMB2.txt`

Comment: Any other suggestion?